Compiling wxWidgets applications in VS Code using Mingw64
I'm trying to compile the wxWidgets grid sample application in Visual Studio Code using Mingw64.
So far I haven't been successful despite intensive search for potential root causes and solutions. The application builds properly if I use the existing makefile.gcc from the command prompt, but inside VS Code I get errors indicating that the wx include files are either not found or not properly included (included in griddemo.cpp before griddemo.h).
First code lines in the griddemo.h file:
class GridApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE;
};
class GridFrame : public wxFrame
{
    wxGrid         *grid;
#if wxUSE_LOG
    wxTextCtrl     *logWin;
    wxLogTextCtrl  *logger;
#endif // wxUSE_LOG

    void SetDefaults();

    void ToggleRowLabels( wxCommandEvent& );
    void ToggleColLabels( wxCommandEvent& );

Corresponding Extract of the error list:
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\griddemo.h:16:1: error: expected class-name before '{' token    16 | {
| ^
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\griddemo.h:18:17: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration    18 |     bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE;
|                 ^
|                  ;
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\griddemo.h:18:19: error: 'wxOVERRIDE' does not name a type    18 |     bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE;
|                   ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\griddemo.h:23:1: error: expected class-name before '{' token    23 | {
| ^
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\griddemo.h:32:27: error: 'wxCommandEvent' has not been declared    32 |     void ToggleRowLabels( wxCommandEvent& );
|                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\griddemo.h:33:27: error: 'wxCommandEvent' has not been declared    33 |     void ToggleColLabels( wxCommandEvent& );
|                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The task.json file has this content:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "C++ Debug Build wxWidgets 3.2.6 application",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\build-debug\\grid.exe",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\**",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-O0",
                "-IC:\\wxWidgets-3.2.6\\include",
                "-IC:\\wxWidgets-3.2.6\\lib\\gcc_dll\\mswud",
                "-DWXUSINGDLL=1",
                "-D__WXMSW__=1",
                "-D_UNICODE=1",
                "-D_DEBUG=1",
                "-Wall",
                "-LC:\\wxWidgets-3.2.6\\lib\\gcc-dll",
                "-lwxbase32ud",
                "-lwxmsw32ud_core",
                "-lwxmsw32ud_aui",
                "-lwxmsw32ud_adv"
             ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "detail": "Generated task for wxWidgets build"
        }
    ]
}

and the c_cpp_properties.json this:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "wxWidgets",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/wxWidgets-3.2.6/include",
                "C:/wxWidgets-3.2.6/lib/gcc_dll/mswud"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG=1",
                "UNICODE=1",
                "_UNICODE=1",
                "__WXMSW__=1",
                "WXUSINGDLL=1"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "C:/wxWidgets-3.2.6/include",
                    "C:/wxWidgets-3.2.6/lib/gcc_dll/mswud"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Information about VS Code:
Version: 1.95.2 (user setup)
Commit: e8653663e8840adaf45af01eab5c627a5af81807
Date: 2024-11-07T11:07:22.054Z
Electron: 32.2.1
ElectronBuildId: 10427718
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.0
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

The executed task as shown in the terminal window:
g++ -g -o C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\build-debug\grid.exe C:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\samples\grid\** -std=c++17 -O0 -IC:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\include -I.\..\..\samples -I.\..\..\include -I. -IC:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -DWXUSINGDLL=1 -D__WXMSW__=1 -D_UNICODE=1 -DNDEBUG=0 -Wall -LC:\wxWidgets-3.2.6\lib\gcc_dll -lwxbase32ud -lwxmsw32ud_core -lwxmsw32ud_aui -lwxmsw32ud_adv

I'm pretty sure it is something small and stupid but I have run out of ideas.

Compare the command ran by the makefile with the one you run in tasks.json.

It looks like it's missing an include for some reason so it doesn't know what at wxApp is and a few other types: wxOVERRIDE and wxCommandEvent

One thing I see is you have defines in the c_cpp_preprocessor.json but don't use -D to define these symbols in your tasks.json in the args:

@ultrajunkie, please look at samples\minimal folder. It has an example of the CMake configuration file. Use it and fix your own.

@drescherjm: I added the definitions... same result. Igor: I checked the configuration file, but this is not exactly helping me. My suspicion is more that VS Code has issues accessing the include folder(s) (for whatever reason). I added the task command in my question. Maybe one of you sees the issue.

@UltraJunkie, you task.json is missing include folder. Please add one and try again. ;-)

You would get a completely different error if it can't find the header files. That is unless you have headers of the same name in your include directories but with different contents.

@Igor: please correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that the option "-I" defines the include folder(s). As you can see in the g++ call, there are actually 5

@drescherjm: I was thinking the same, but that means, the include files are found but either not read at all or not properly interpreted (and both would be strange). Using the "verbose" option, the output reveals that the include dirs are definitely found

@UltraJunkie, all you need is 2 but you task.json shows only 1.

I updated the task.json section to reflect the latest status. The result is still the same

@UltraJunkie, how exactly did you build wxWidgets library? What was the command? And what is wrong with using the binary produced by the Terminal? You said it compiled fine...

The command was
mingw32-make -j10 -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug
mingw32-make -j10 -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
mingw32-make -j10 -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug
mingw32-make -j10 -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
And regarding the terminal compilation: the purpose of a tool like VS Code is to work inside not only for editing but also for building and debugging. Specifically I don't want to invest time for building my own makefiles if I can use a tool for that
